# display order product name in my account of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce 3.06. My question is that how can I show Product Name in my order instead of just order number. Instead of order number I want it to show name of the product purchased so that customers can easily track status of items.

Below is the code of my-order.php file from Woocommerce.

```
    <?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * @deprecated  2.6.0 this template file is no longer used. My Account shortcode uses orders.php.
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) ) );


if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Recent orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                printf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count );
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        ),
                                    );

                                    if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is this still works ?, can i have a help here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395029/display-product-description-in-my-account-orders-table-of-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function, means put the below function to `functions.php` or in any custom plugin and replace `$order->get_order_number()` with `the_dramatist_get_order_prod_name( $order )` in your `my-order.php`.

```
/**
 * Returns comma separated product names of an Order
 *
 * @param $order WC_Order
 *
 * @return string
 */
function the_dramatist_get_order_prod_name( $order ) {
    $prod_names = array();
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
        $prod_names[] = $lineItem['name'];
    }
    return implode(",", $prod_names );
}
```

---

> Remember, it will return comma separated string with all the products name of an order.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it not possible to return all the names and not just one?

Comment: Yep. Obviously possible. So you want to print all the product names separated by comma ? right ?

Comment: Please check this screenshot - http://imgur.com/a/zmCnV. What I want is that instead of order no it to show the name of the item with link to the detailed order summary.

Comment: Follow the instructions I gave above the answer. Replace `$order->get_order_number()` with `the_dramatist_get_order_prod_name( $order )`. OK ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144245/discussion-between-the-dramatist-and-mayank-gupta).