# display product description in my account orders table of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display the description of the first item only next to the order id so if there is 3 items and all of them have descriptions i want it to show next to the order id the description of the first item only.

Normally: #3214

What i expect: #3214 | Product Description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to dothe above -

```
function modify_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) ) return $order_id;
    $first_line_item_descrp = '';
    foreach ( $order->get_items( 'line_item' ) as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product      = $item->get_product();
        $first_line_item_descrp = $product->get_description();
        break;
    }
    return $order_id . ' | ' . $first_line_item_descrp;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'modify_woocommerce_order_number', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi,

This solution works like a charm thank you, but what if i want it to work on the page of the dashboard too ? as i already have the orders table added to the dashboard page too not the orders page only as the screenshot below https://prnt.sc/pjm3ij

Comment: Then replace above `is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' )`  with `is_account_page()` checking.

Comment: can you help in this as i tried the provided answer but didn't work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259245/change-payment-gateway-data-sent-to-product-description

Comment: Hi, I tried to make the product description only look bold so i tried this but didn't work

    `return $order_id . ' | ' . "<strong>".$first_line_item_descrp."</strong>";`

Can you help ?

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid. Actually if you see the above filter source in woocommerce, then you can see that it's converted the filtered return type to `string`. Whatever the html we apply in our filter return value, it will treat as a string. In this case the only way to do so is override the `myaccount/orders.php` file and do the changes.

Comment: Ok its ok doesn't matter thank you, but if i used the php snippet without need to make it bold that you provided before will be ok right ?, **If yes**: can you help to modify this code to make it not next to order id but in a separate coulmn after the order id ?, i have a code below but it gets the name and just need a little modification to get the description of the first product only not all the products. i would be thankful if you provided it in a separate answer below